# Changing the output directory when recreating SSH host keys with ssh-keygen (the -f switch doesn't prevent ssh-keygen from writing to /etc/ssh/)

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

I've been trying to start an additional sshd process on a remote machine. I've created a working directory with the new sshd config file I'd like to use.

When I try to run sshd using the config file in this directory, it complains it can't find any host keys. I've tried to create missing host keys by running `ssh-keygen -A` with the `-f` switch to specify the location of my working directory but ssh-keygen continues trying to place the keys in `/etc/ssh/` instead of the directory I specified. I don't have access to /etc/ssh, so it fails.

How can I generate these keys without access to this path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-A` option tells `ssh-keygen` to generate **host keys**.  According to the manual page, the intended use of `ssh-keygen` is

> Normally each user wishing to use SSH with public key authentication runs
>   this once to create the authentication key in `~/.ssh/identity`,
>   `~/.ssh/id_ecdsa`, `~/.ssh/id_dsa` or `~/.ssh/id_rsa`.  **Additionally**, the system administrator may use this to generate host keys.

The synopsis lists the `-A` on a line by itself, with no other options:

```
SYNOPSIS
     ssh-keygen [-q] [-b bits] -t type [-N new_passphrase] [-C comment]
                [-f output_keyfile]
     ssh-keygen -p [-P old_passphrase] [-N new_passphrase] [-f keyfile]
     ssh-keygen -i [-m key_format] [-f input_keyfile]
     ssh-keygen -e [-m key_format] [-f input_keyfile]
     ssh-keygen -y [-f input_keyfile]
     ssh-keygen -c [-P passphrase] [-C comment] [-f keyfile]
     ssh-keygen -l [-f input_keyfile]
     ssh-keygen -B [-f input_keyfile]
     ssh-keygen -D pkcs11
     ssh-keygen -F hostname [-f known_hosts_file] [-l]
     ssh-keygen -H [-f known_hosts_file]
     ssh-keygen -R hostname [-f known_hosts_file]
     ssh-keygen -r hostname [-f input_keyfile] [-g]
     ssh-keygen -G output_file [-v] [-b bits] [-M memory] [-S start_point]
     ssh-keygen -T output_file -f input_file [-v] [-a num_trials] [-K checkpt]
                [-W generator]
     ssh-keygen -s ca_key -I certificate_identity [-h] [-n principals]
                [-O option] [-V validity_interval] [-z serial_number] file ...
     ssh-keygen -L [-f input_keyfile]
     ssh-keygen -A
```

So (aside from modifying the source and compiling it yourself), what you are asking is not its intended use.

Further reading:

- [**`ssh-keygen`** — authentication key generation, management and conversion](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh-keygen.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to docker, which is why I wanted to do this, to create a new, persistent host-key that would be outside container, I used the following:

```
docker run -d --name get_host_keys lscr.io/linuxserver/openssh-server:latest
sleep 5
docker cp get_host_keys:/etc/ssh/. .
rm *config*
docker stop get_host_keys
docker rm get_host_keys
```